# how to insert default text in every new line(multi line texbox) c#

Tags: c#

I want to create program like command prompt, and now i got error when trying to show `c:\user>` in every new line in my `Text-box` , I try this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(Oko);

}
private void Oko(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + "c:\\user>";
    }
}
```

but every time I press enter the `c:\user` become so many
How do I fix this? thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

> but every time i press enter the "c:\user"

Because you have written the code that does precisely that. Now, if you want to change that you should add some key combination so that *C:\User* is entered only on that specific key combination.

Comment: but, in command prompt every time you press enter you will get "c:\user" , can i do that too?

Comment: no not every time. If you haven't written anything after C:\User only then will it enter the same text in the next line. Else it will validate your input.

Comment: and can i make the c:\user cant be deleted?